# Blender crashes when baking particles

Tags: particles

I'm still rather new to Blender and hope to find support here.

Blender is immediately crashing when I try to render my boid - particle simulation (particles that follow a smoke flow).
I'm not sure if the number of the planes particles (12'000) is just too much.

Im using a M1 Max Macbook Pro with:

- 10‑Core CPU
- 16-Core GPU
- 64 GB Ram
- More than 700 GB of free memory on my local drive

What I have tried so far:

- I am using Cycles GPU compute (and tried everything else, CPU, experimental, supported ... )
- I am using disk cache to bake
- I have metalIRT (experimental) checked in render settings
- I reduced the resolution of the format (to 1920 px)

...

I assume my hardware should be able to handle it??

I have no chance of working on my project currently, which is really sad. Would anyone have an idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Hi. Blender Stack Exchange is a question and answer platform for questions about using Blender and its Python API. Crashes are not part of normal Blender operation and are usually caused by bugs. There is nothing we can do about bugs here in Blender Stack Exchange answers except maybe recommend updating GPU drivers, so questions like this are considered off-topic. Consider reporting this to developers as a bug (Help menu -> Report a Bug).

Comment: Uh oh, thank you for clearing that @MartynasŽiemys. I'll still leave the post (for now) in case others make the same confusion.